# Running LaTeX after Sweaving halt

Tags: r, emacs, latex, knitr, sweave

I am trying to use the below combination in my work:

1. "Emacs for Windows Modified 24.3-modified-4" by Prof. Vincent Goulet
2. MiKTex 2.9

I changed "Ess Swv Processor" from "sweave" to "knitr", and below is my problem.

<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> successfully sweaved my ".Rnw" file into ".tex" file, and produced all the figures into a folder called "figure" at the same path level with this ".tex" file.

After I do <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>, I got message:

`"Searching for program: permission denied, texi2pdf"`.

Can someone tell me what's missing here?

Comment: Is `texi2pdf`'s directory in your `PATH` and `exec-path`? To check `PATH` do `M-x ielm` this will open an elisp repl. Enter `(getenv "PATH")` and press enter. To get the value of `exec-path` do `C-h v exec-path RET`

Comment: Hi Iqbal, I tried `getenv "PATH"`, but got message of `*** IELM error ***  More than one sexp in input`.

Comment: After some search on internet, I understand that MiKTex doesn't have "texi2pdf". This was discussed in [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.ess.general/5066). Some remedies are also suggested there. In minibuffer, I could have just used "left" or "right" arrow on the keyboard to choose  `{pdflatex | make | texi2pdf}` (whereas default is `{texi2pdf | pdflatex | make}`), then  ".tex" file will be successfully translated to PDF file.

Comment: @Yamming, about ielm error you should have enter `(getenv "PATH")`, with the brackets, sorry for not being clear. So I guess you have got this working.